# Limit of $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\left|\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-x)^k}-1\right|$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Fix a real number $x>0$.

> **Question**: What is the following limit?
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\left|\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-x)^k}-1\right|
> \end{align}

---

Denote the quotient by $Q_{n,k}$:
\begin{align}
Q_{n,k}:=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-x)^k}
\end{align}
It is easy to see that for each *fixed* $k$, we have $Q_{n,k}\to 1$ and so $|Q_{n,k}-1|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, but now the maximum is taken before taking limit so one has better to be more careful here. In fact, more importantly is that the maximum is taken over the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ which, although is finite, is depending also on $n$. Had this finite set been independent of $n$, we could have applied the fact that the limit of maximum equals the maximum of limits, and the job would be easy.

---

Any comment, suggestion or answer is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Can you, assuming $n > x$, find the $k$ for which $Q_{n,k}$ takes it's maximum?

Comment: @Ingix I'd think that's the hard part. Any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt a proof that the **limit is equal to 1** in below. Still, I'd like to thank the users @Ingix and @metamorphy for their reply.

---

Since at the end we will take limit as $n\to\infty$, we may assume that $n$ is large. At the moment let us assume $n>x$. The first step is to study the pattern of $Q_{n,k}$ as $k$ increases. It turns out that:

> **Lemma 1**. The expression $Q_{n,k}$, as a function of $k$, is
>
> - increasing on the interval $\left[1,\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right]$ (and is in fact strictly increasing on $\left[1,\lfloor x\rfloor\right]$);
>   and
> - strictly decreasing on $\left[\lfloor x\rfloor+1,n\right]$.

That is to say,
\begin{align}
1<Q_{n,1}<\cdots<Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor}\leq Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+1}>Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+2}>\cdots>Q_{n,n}
\end{align}
This is easy to prove. Indeed, one only needs to write
\begin{align}
Q_{n,k}=Q_{n,k-1}\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{n-x}
\end{align}
and see, from $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x<\lfloor x\rfloor+1$, that one has
\begin{align}
\frac{n-k+1}{n-x}\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
\leq 1 & \text{if} & k\leq\lfloor x\rfloor+1 \\
 & & \\ 
>1 & \text{if} & k>\lfloor x\rfloor+1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
(with equality if and only if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k=\lfloor x\rfloor+1$).  $\qquad\square$

Now, if $Q_{n,k}\geq 1$ for all $k$ then it is clear that the max of $|Q_{n,k}-1|=Q_{n,k}-1$ is attained at $k=\lfloor x\rfloor+1$. Unfortunately this may not be the case in general. For large $k$ the quantity $Q_{n,k}$ may be getting $<1$. In fact, for large $n$ this is indeed the case:

> **Lemma 2**. Assume $n>2\lfloor x\rfloor+3$. Then, with $k_0:=2\lfloor x\rfloor+3$, we have
> $$Q_{n,k}<1$$
> for all $k_0\leq k\leq n$.

Since $k_0>\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ and since $Q_{n,k}$ is decreasing on $\left[\lfloor x\rfloor+1,n\right]$ by **Lemma 1**, it suffices to show that $Q_{n,k_0}<1$. Once we express $Q_{n,k_0}$ in the following form, it will be immediately clear that this is true:
\begin{align}
Q_{n,k_0}&=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots\left[n-2\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)\right]}{(n-x)^{2\lfloor x\rfloor+3}} \\
%%%
&=\frac{n\left[n-\left(2\lfloor x\rfloor+2\right)\right]}{(n-x)^2}\cdot
\frac{(n-1)\left[n-\left(2\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)\right]}{(n-x)^2}\cdot\cdots\cdot
\frac{\left[n-\lfloor x\rfloor\right]
\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+2\right)\right]}{(n-x)^2}\cdot
\frac{n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)}{(n-x)} \\
%%%
&=\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}
\underbrace{\frac{\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)+k\right]\cdot
\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)-k\right]}{(n-x)^2}}_{<1}\cdot
\underbrace{\frac{n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)}{(n-x)}}_{<1}
\end{align}
Each of these factors is strictly less than $1$: For every $1\leq k\leq\lfloor x\rfloor+1$,
\begin{align}
\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)+k\right]\cdot
\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)-k\right]
&=\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)\right]^2-k^2 \\
%%%
&<\left[n-\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+1\right)\right]^2 \\
%%%
&<(n-x)^2
\end{align}
This proves **Lemma 2**. $\qquad\square$

For even larger $n$ (than assumed in **Lemma 2**), it is also indeed true that $Q_{n,k}$ becomes close to $0$ as $k$ getting closer to $n$. One can observe this easily by plotting a graph. For our purpose, however, we do not need this and so we will not attempt to prove it.

The existence of $k_0$ also implies, by Well-ordering principle, that $k_{\min}:=\min\{k:Q_{n,k}<1\}$ exists, though we note that $k_0$ may not necessarily be equal to $k_{\min}$. Nevertheless, since one must have $k_{\min}>\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ (because $Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+1}>1$), thus by **Lemma 1**, $Q_{n,k}$ is decreasing on $[k_{\min},n]$, but on this interval one also has $Q_{n,k}<1$ (by definition of $k_{\min}$), so it must be that
\begin{align}
\max_{k_{\min}\leq k\leq n}|Q_{n,k}-1|=1-Q_{n,n}
\end{align}
Meanwhile, it is clear that
\begin{align}
\max_{1\leq k<k_{\min}}|Q_{n,k}-1|=Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+1}-1
\end{align}
At this point, we have thus reduced the number of "candidates/competitors" for the maximum from $n$ to $2$:
\begin{align}
\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|Q_{n,k}-1|
=\max\left\{Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+1}-1,1-Q_{n,n}\right\}
\end{align}
Now the rest are standard exercises from calculus:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+1}=1,\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty}Q_{n,n}=0
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|Q_{n,k}-1|
&=\max\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(Q_{n,\lfloor x\rfloor+1}-1\right),
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-Q_{n,n}\right)\right\}
=1
\end{align}
This completes the proof.